# Market App crashes on Samsung Galaxy Ace

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-ace, crashes

i have samsung galaxy ace, yesterday i rooted my phone and installed the link2sd application, everything was fine, today when i tried to install an application using market, the market just crashes while opening, i uninstall the app, and got the new apk from internet and install that, same happening with that, after i read a review on internet, that if the market app crashes, just clear the data from settings, i did the same, it was working fine, but when i clicked on Accept and Download button to install the app, the market again start crashing, do anyone have any idea why is this happening, is it because i rooted the phone and partitioned the SDCard and installed the Link2SD application yesterday, did anyone have faced this issue.

Comment: Try to get the log of the error, and post it here.  aLogCat app from Market can help with that, or you can manually do that via ADB.

Comment: Did you do a factory reset after rooting? I know, that's not always necessary -- but if you run into trouble like that, it may help (did for me), especially when multiple apps are affected by this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

go into Settings>Applications select ALL applications. Scroll the the very bottom of the list as you should see an app named "Downloads" select it, and then change it from "Disabled" to "Enabled".